# Cannot enable grayed-out (.setEnabled(false)) JtextField or JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Unfortunately, I cannot turn on .setEnable() for a JTextField, or a JTextField (tried both). It keeps remaining gray, so users cannot type. Please help me out.

Details: taTwo can be either a JTextField or JTextArea but any I try cannot be enabled. It should be disabled for A but should be enabled for B, so if user choose A he/she can NOT enter a value in taTwo field, but if the user choose B he/she can write in taTwo.

The method is the following:

```
public void btnAddtreeAction() {
    this.btnAddtree.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
            dialogPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,60));
            
            String[] choices = {"A", "B"};
            JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);
            
            JTextArea taOne = new JTextArea(1,30);
            JTextField taTwo = new JTextField();
            taTwo.setEnabled(false);

            Object[] myObject = {"Options:", cb,
                                "Input first:", taOne,
                                "Input second:", taTwo};
            
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, myObject, "Form", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            
            if (cb.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A")) {
               //something will happen here
            } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("B")) {
                taTwo.setEnabled(true);
              //something will happen here
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `JTextField` and `JTextArea` every time `addActionListener` is triggered? Post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `actionPerformed` method, you are creating a **new** `JTextField` which you are not adding to your GUI. I presume that you have another variable named `taTwo` somehere in the code that you did not post. You are **not** changing that variable inside the `actionPerformed` method. Try removing this line of your code:

```java
JTextField taTwo = new JTextField();
```

Comment: Originally, the concept was the following: When a user hits a button (btnAddtree) a popup input window appears, if the user choose A from the combobox can fill only the taOne, but if the user choose B can fill both taOne and taTwo. Last, I removed taTwo. Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you need to move your enablemet/disablement code into another `ActionListener` and add it to your combobox. Something like this:

```
public void btnAddtreeAction() {
    this.btnAddtree.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
            dialogPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,60));
            
            String[] choices = {"A", "B"};
            JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<String>(choices);
            
            JTextArea taOne = new JTextArea(1,30);
            JTextField taTwo = new JTextField();
            taTwo.setEnabled(false);
            cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (cb.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("A")) {
                        taTwo.setEnabled(false);
                        //something will happen here
                    } else if (cb.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("B")) {
                        taTwo.setEnabled(true);
                        //something will happen here
                    }
                }
            });

            Object[] myObject = {"Options:", cb,
                                "Input first:", taOne,
                                "Input second:", taTwo};
            
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, myObject, "Form", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
    });
}
```